# EditorFor Template for repeating data on a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to setup an EditorTemplate for a repeating class (Offer) - however, I'm having trouble getting the EditorTemplate to work correctly:

My ViewModel is:

```
    public class OfferVM
    {
    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string RoomTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Layout { get; set; }
    public decimal RoomRate { get; set; }
    public string Inclusions { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeInOffer { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller Get code is:

```
    //
    // GET: /Offer/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var roomtypes = db.RoomTypes.Include(r => r.Property).ToList();
        IList<OfferVM> offerVM = Mapper.Map<IList<RoomType>, IList<OfferVM>>(roomtypes);
        return View(offerVM);
    }
```

The controller works fine - I can see it populated in VS.

My Create.cshtml code is:

```
@model IEnumerable<FGBS.ViewModels.OfferVM>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form().Type(FormType.Horizontal))) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>


<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoomTypeId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PropertyId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Layout)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoomRate)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Inclusions)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Property)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IncludeInOffer)
    </th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>

    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.OfferVM)

    </table>
```

Then in my Views/Home/EditorTemplates folder I have my OfferVM.cshtml file:

```
@model FGBS.ViewModels.OfferVM

@{
    Layout = null;
}
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomTypeId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomTypeId)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyId)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomTypeName)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Layout)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Layout)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoomRate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoomRate)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Inclusions)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Inclusions)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IncludeInOffer)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncludeInOffer)
  </td>

    </tr>
```

However, when I run the code, I get the error:

''System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'OfferVM' and no extension method 'OfferVM' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

I'm sure I've missed something simple - but any advice on how to correct my problem, would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.OfferVM)` is wrong, since the `Model` is already the IEnumeration. You probably messed up your ViewModel while refactoring? I'd suggest to have a container ViewModel for `Create.cshtml`, so instead of Model `IEnumerable<FGBS.ViewModels.OfferVM>` you have a Model like `CreateViewModel` class which then has a property `Offers`, which is a `IList<OfferVM>`.

Your Model code:

```
public class OfferVM
{
    ....
}

public class CreateViewModel {
    public IList<OfferVM> Offers { get; set; }
    public OfferVM Header {
        get {
            return Offers.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Your Controller code:

```
var vm = new CreateViewModel();
vm.Offers = Mapper.Map<IList<RoomType>, IList<OfferVM>>(roomtypes);
return View(vm);
```

Your Create.cshtml starts with:

```
@model FGBS.ViewModels.CreateViewModel
```

In your TH's you will write something like:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Header.RoomTypeId)
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you - that's got me passed this issue - I'll post another query for the EditorFor template not populating now (but not erroring - so thanks!!)